# ModelForeign key fails to create a column id linked to the object in Django

Tags: python, django, attributes, models

I can't figure out why the `ForeignKey` is not working in my `models.py`.

I closely followed the tutorial and all I need to do is to make `Games` a part of `Department` (same with `Choices` and part of the `Poll`). Same games can be part of different departments.

Here's the code for my `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models

class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __unicode__(self):  
        return self.name

class Game(models.Model):
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department) 
    name_of_the_game = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __unicode__(self):  
        return self.name_of_the_game
```

I created the SQLite tables and did everything like in the tutorial.

This is the error that it gives me in python shell:

```
>>> from logins.models import Department, Game 
>>> p = Department.objects.get(pk = 1)
>>> p.game_set.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 71, in __repr__
    data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 96, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 854, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 220, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 710, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 781, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 69, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 99, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 450, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
OperationalError: no such column: logins_game.department_id
```

Maybe I am just missing some very basic step, but even after reading related docs on Django site, I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: How did you create your tables? syncdb? Can it be that you added foreign key after you performed syncdb?

Comment: Yes, I did create it! And I did it before I made the foreignKeys =, thats why I am confused :/

Comment: So, if you don't have any data in the tables, I suggest you to delete them and run syncdb again. In a long term I suggest you to use South as @krs said. http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: Thank you! I'll try that or delete the database. 
How do I delete it though?

Comment: Depends which DB you are using, something like `drop table XXX` or `drop database XXX` in your db shell.

Comment: @dragoon I am using SQLite. how would I delete the whole database?

Comment: just delete the file.

Comment: So I used this command: ./manage.py sqlclear app_name to clear my SQLite database (and it worked, as it said that it dropped the tables) and then I reran and recreated all the tables again, and it still gives me the same error! That the column does not exist! What could be wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: please follow my advice, to delete the database you need to delete the file. As you can see from the docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#sqlclear-appname-appname) sqlclear command only prints SQL to drop table, **not actually drops it**.

Comment: Yeah, but then I am not sure how to actually delete a database :/ What command should I use?

Comment: SQLite database is self-contained in one file that you specified in the settings. Deleting the file will delete the database.

Comment: Wow, that took a while! @dragoon thanks so much for help! And sorry for my maybe silly questions, I am new to django and databases. But it worked! :)

Comment: @dragoon you could make your comment an answer, I will accept it. Thanks again thou!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you modified your database schema after creating the database.

You need to migrate your apps or recreate your database if you don't have any data.
To migrate your apps, try [South](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). To recreate the database, for example if you are using SQLite, you can just delete the database file specified in your settings, and the run `syncdb` command again.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create the database tables, then changed the models?

Django does not keep the database and the models in sync, you either need to use South for that, or destroy and rebuild the database when you change the models.

Comment: I made the models first and then created the database. That's the problem :( Not sure, why it doesn't want to recognize it

that's what it gives me when I create the database: 

BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "logins_department" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "name" varchar(200) NOT NULL
)
;
CREATE TABLE "logins_game" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "department_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "logins_department" ("id"),
    "name_of_the_game" varchar(200) NOT NULL
)
;

COMMIT;

Answer (score 0):

Have you ran `python manage.py syncdb` command after defining your `models.py` ?

Comment: Yes, I did! I even redid it to check couple of times. And did everything from scratch ones. I am really not sure, why is it not working :/ 
Maybe I should some id in brackets for ForeignKey or something?

Comment: It seems like you have changed the model after running `syncdb`.  Try running `syncdb` again and see if you get the same error.